# How do I get expected behavior from SKPhysicsJointSpring?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I'm trying out a spring joint in SpriteKit (i.e. `SKPhysicsJointSpring`) with this simple scene. Pretty much, I've got a red sprite acting as the "ceiling", and then an orange sprite acting as a mass "block" that is supposed to be suspended from it by a spring (note: I did not draw anything to connect the two squares, but just imagine there was a spring there).

[image]

With the default gravity, I would expect that the orange block would begin to bounce up and down, but in fact, it just sits there. To further my confusion, if I uncomment the application of some force at the end of the scene's `-didMoveToView:` method, the `x` direction of the vector seems to actually be affecting the orange block (it begins to act as a pendulum), but the `y` direction vector doesn't seem to affect anything. It's as if the spring is really acting like a rigid rod. Is that supposed to happen?

And finally, why does the pendulum-like motion eventually dampen out? It seems that the default friction is `0.0`, and I have not applied any friction myself. Can someone help me better understand this `SKPhysicsJointSpring`?

```
#import "XYZMainScene.h"

@interface XYZMainScene ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) SKSpriteNode *ceiling;
@property (nonatomic, strong) SKSpriteNode *block;

@end

@implementation XYZMainScene

- (void)didMoveToView:(SKView *)view {

    SKSpriteNode *ceiling = self.ceiling;
    [self addChild:ceiling];

    SKSpriteNode *block = self.block;
    [self addChild:block];

    SKPhysicsJointSpring *spring = [SKPhysicsJointSpring jointWithBodyA:ceiling.physicsBody
                                                                  bodyB:block.physicsBody
                                                                anchorA:ceiling.position
                                                                anchorB:block.position];
    [self.physicsWorld addJoint:spring];

//    [block.physicsBody applyForce:CGVectorMake(60, -100)];
}

- (SKSpriteNode *)ceiling {

    if (!_ceiling) {
        _ceiling = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[SKColor redColor]
                                                size:CGSizeMake(30, 30)];

        _ceiling.position    = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width/2, 400);
        _ceiling.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithEdgeFromPoint:_ceiling.position
                                                            toPoint:_ceiling.position];
    }
    return _ceiling;
}

- (SKSpriteNode *)block {

    if (!_block) {
        _block = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[SKColor orangeColor]
                                              size:CGSizeMake(50,50)];

        _block.position    = CGPointMake(self.ceiling.position.x, self.ceiling.position.y - 200);
        _block.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:_block.frame.size];
    }
    return _block;
}

@end
```

Comment: the joints have internal properties (same as Box2d) like dampening that SK simply doesn't expose

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change the `frequency` and `damping` properties of the `SKPhysicsJointSpring`.

```
SKPhysicsJointSpring *spring = [SKPhysicsJointSpring jointWithBodyA:ceiling.physicsBody
                                                                  bodyB:block.physicsBody
                                                                anchorA:ceiling.position
                                                                anchorB:block.position];
spring.frequency = 1.0; //gives the spring some elasticity.
spring.damping = 0.0; //Will remove damping to create the 'pendulum'   
[self.physicsWorld addJoint:spring];
```

Read up on the SKPhysicsJointSpring class reference [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKPhysicsJointSpring_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/SKPhysicsJointSpring).

Comment: According to the class reference page, the default value for `damping` is `0.0`. I have also tried playing with the `frequency`, but neither `damping` nor `frequency` seems to affect the motion. It's as if the value is ignored... Were you able to verify that setting the frequency and damping like that will solve my problem?

Comment: Yeah, I copied ur code and checked it on my system. The frequency value made it go up and down like a spring.

Comment: I also set the lineardamping and friction properties of the block's physicsBody

Comment: Did u call applyImpulse with a dy variable?

Comment: Well I tried out the `frequency` again, and you were right - it did work. I'm not sure what was different from the last time I tried it, but this seems to be the correct solution. Thanks!

Comment: I think I discovered why it didn't work that time. I had no idea what value I should use for `frequency`, so I set it to an arbitrary value of `20.0`. Turns out this number is so high that it shows no movement at all. I needed to start at a lower value like `1.0` as you suggested.